# Implementation of BDD for Backbone UI and Spring REST API

Tags: spring, rest, backbone.js, marionette, bdd

So, We have this application which is developed with 2 different languages:

1. Frontend - This is a backbone/ marionette application which just takes the json response formats it nicely and displays to user
2. Backend - A spring application which talks to db and returns a json REST response to frontend UI.

The thing is, i want to do BDD. I am confused whether:
1. To test the UI features using BDD or
2. Test Rest calls for BDD?

What is the proper approach to implement BDD in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Behaviour Driven Development, BDD, is a collaboration technique. It can be used for automation as well.

I would consider specifying the behaviour your business stakeholders find important using Gherkin. When you have had a discussion about the most important features, then consider automating them. The automation can be done in any layer in your application. Some of them through your user interface and some directly against your back end.

I wrote a bit about it a while ago: http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2016/03/26/where-should-you-use-behaviour-driven-development-bdd